# Communicating synchronously with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, synchronous, message-passing

I'm looking for a way to send and receive message synchronously from a chrome extension. The idea would be to call a function defined in my extension from a traditional web page (web app) in a synchronous way so that i don't have to wait before receiving the result.

Unfortunately, i read [Synchronous message passing in chrome extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996281/synchronous-message-passing-in-chrome-extensions) and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135095. Both say that it's not possible.

But i thought that the XMLHttpRequest can make synchronous call.

I know this is certainly not possible but i'm asking anyway.. Would there be a way to use the XMLHttpRequest object in such a way that we could communicate synchronously with an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for you, but the answer is still **no**. I don't see why using XMLHttpRequests would help to make any kind of operation that is done (asynchronously) with the Chrome API, but let's assume you've got some `content_script.js` that runs inside some page, and you need to send a message to `background.js`. **How would you accomplish this by using an `XMLHttpRequest`?** Making a request to your `background.js` will not give you the chance to run its code, but only to read it. That's because most of the API methods used in `background.js` aren't available in a content script. That's the same for any other asynchronous operation that happens inside a Chrome extension.

So the problem here is that **Chrome Extensions cannot use `XMLHttpRequest`s to communicate within their environment**, thus, you just can't use them in that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought maybe someone would have some workaround but indeed your answer makes sense. thanks again

Comment: @Sam if my answer solved your question, then consider marking it as correct to close your question and let other people find it easily.