# Chrome Extension: have extension edit its web_accessible_resources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to keep a JSON file in the extension's `web_accessible_resources` so that it can be read by a content script through a synchronous XHR (the synchronous part is important, that's why I'm using a XHR).

However this file is supposed to reflect actions the user takes through the extension's interface, so when the user changes something there, the JSON file is rewritten by the background page (this can happen asynchronously). This way, next time the content script reads the file, it will be up to date.

Is there any way for an extension to modify a file that's listed under its `web_accessible_resources`?

Alternatively, as a last resource, it would be okay to make the extension open the file in a text editor and have the user directly edit it, but I'm afraid that would make Chrome assume the extension is getting compromised and disable it.

Comment: Why does it need to be synchronous?

Comment: The content script needs to inject some code before anything from the page is loaded, but that code depends on information the content script doesn't have, so it needs to fetch it (synchronously) from either a file or the background page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to modify the contents of a file in the extension.

What you can do in this situation is to employ `chrome.storage.onChanged` event.

1. Your background page updates the information in `chrome.storage`.
2. This triggers `chrome.storage.onChanged` in the content script. You react to it by saving a local copy of the data. You don't even need to query the storage: new data is available in the event.
3. You access the local copy of the data synchronously.

This does not address the issue of having the data when the content script just starts executing, since you have to populate it initially asynchronously. But a synchronous XHR is a very clunky idea.

Some more ideas are covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24653385/934239). Any of them are pretty convoluted hacks though, and Chrome's [official position is "won't happen"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54257).

P.S. And just in case someone comes to this question really seeking variable response to an XHR, one can use `chrome.webRequest` API to redirect to a `data:` URI containing the data; the catch is that the URI itself must be constructed / available synchronously.

Comment: I've used the File API method explained in the question you linked and it works. As you said it's a bit of a hack, but there just doesn't seem to be a proper "clean" way to achieve what I want. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible, since this is why there is a [fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem). I dont know your special use case, but isnt there a possibility of loading the file once the extension starts? In most cases the loading should be done before the user can even interact.

Comment: The file needs to be read by a content script, so every time a page is visited. I considered [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to make the needed information known to the content script, but both of them are asynchronous.